# How to use Bootstrap 4 flexbox to fill available content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have an angular app that uses bootstrap 4. I have a nav bar that sticks to the top, and I want to add content that fills the remaining space in the browser. Aside from the navbar at the top, I have another div that itself contains header and footer content.  Between the header and footer, I have a main content section, and I want that section (`#two` in my example below) to fill all empty space.

I thought I could use css flexbox to accomplish this, but my simple non-bootstrap flexbox example seemed to do nothing when I moved into the bootstrap world. I was using [these docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) to try to figure this out.

I thought using `align-self-stretch` should help accomplish this goal, but it sort of looks like the containing elements might be sizing themselves just big enough to hold my `#outer` content, so there's no flexbox expanding to be done. I tried naively just adding `height:100%` styles to the containing divs just to try to get some stretching, but that didn't seem to help.

I created this [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TCMq9fI2XqtZNQ1S6OZQ?p=preview) based on @ZimSystem's response. His codeply example seemed to work exactly as I wanted, but when I tried to piece the changes into my simple angular code, the flex stretching didn't happen.  I'm not sure what I'm doing to break it in the conversion.

[image]

This is the entirety of the angular component I am viewing at the moment:

```
<div id="outer" class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
    <div id="one" class="">
        header content <br>
        another line <br>
        And another
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="bg-info h-100 flex-grow">
        main content that I want to expand to cover remaining available height
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="">
        footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the application container showing the navbar and injection point:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md sticky-top bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0">My App</h1>
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/flex">My flex view</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

How can I get my `#two` div to expand to fill the space while having my `#one` and `#three` divs acting as content headers and footers anchored to the top and bottom of the content area?

Comment: When using percent for height, make sure all ascendants also have a height, i.e. `html, body { height: 100%; }` ...another option us to use  viewport units instead, `height: 100vh` on the application container

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Update Bootstrap 4.1.0**

The `flex-grow-1` and `flex-fill` classes are included in Bootstrap 4.1.0

**Update Bootstrap 4.0.0**

Add a `flex-grow` class like this:

```
.flex-grow {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Then, the [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) can be used for the rest of the layout:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md sticky-top bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0">My App</h1>
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="outer" class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
        <div id="one" class="">
            header content
            <br> another line
            <br> And another
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="bg-info h-100 flex-grow">
            main content that I want to expand to cover remaining available height
        </div>
        <div id="three" class="">
            footer content 40px height
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/3ZDkRAghGU

Here's another example with on **Bootstrap 4.3.1** that has a navbar, sidebar and footer with scrolling content area: 
https://www.codeply.com/go/LIaOWljJm8

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Yours works as I was looking for, but I seem to have broken it when moving into a simple angular project at https://plnkr.co/edit/TCMq9fI2XqtZNQ1S6OZQ?p=preview.  Is anything obviously different from yours? I edited my original post to reflect this plunker example.

Answer (score 10):

Your component is wrapped into a `<flex>` element that needs the same flexbox styling to stretch vertically as well, allowing it's content to stretch with it. So adding `class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow"` to the `<flex>` will work. Here's a working fork of [your plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/w0ciDZUr1d5fCfjetRJK?p=preview).

Answer (score 4):

The problem, when using [ZimSystem's markup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642449/1009922) in your Angular plunker, is that the component is inserted in the rendered HTML as an additional container with the `flex` tag:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md sticky-top bg-faded">
        ...
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <flex>
        <div id="outer" class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
            ...
        </div>
    </flex>
</div>
```

In order to make it work as intended, you can remove the outer div from the component and set the flex classes on the component's host container, as shown in [**this modified plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jWwyKh0HSODlKTbGqQOT?p=preview).

```
import {Component, NgModule, HostBinding, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { RouterOutlet, RouterModule } from '@angular/router' 
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
    selector: 'flex',
    template: `
        <div id="one" class="">
            header content
            <br> another line
            <br> And another
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="bg-info h-100 flex-grow">
            main content that I want to expand to cover remaining available height
        </div>
        <div id="three" class="">
            footer content
        </div>
    `
})
export class FlexComponent {
    @HostBinding('class') classes = 'd-flex flex-column flex-grow';  
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can not control the behavor of the class you are using. Just remove all of it and use this css only.

```css
html,
body,
flex {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.two {
  background-color: #123;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<flex>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="one">
      Hey. This is header. <br> Hey. This is header. <br> Hey. This is header. <br> Hey. This is header. <br>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      Hey. This is body
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      Hey. This is footer <br> Hey. This is footer <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</flex>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Add a wrapper component that holds your content blocks, and apply the `flex-grow` class to the one that you want to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}
```

flex.components.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { RouterOutlet, RouterModule } from '@angular/router' 
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'flex',
  host: {'class': 'flex-grow'},
  template: `

<div id="outer" class="d-flex flex-column h-100 flex-grow">
  <div id="one" class="">
    header content
    <br> another line
    <br> And another
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="bg-info flex-grow">
    main content that I want to expand to cover remaining available height
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="">
    footer content
  </div>
</div>        

  ` 
})
export class FlexComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Result - https://plnkr.co/edit/vQS7Jw58zmlVshz9YmQ8?p=preview
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the component grow to fill its container and then have it as a flex column as well so the content will also grow. To do this use `:host` to target the component element.

**flex.component.ts**

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'flex',
    template: `

  <div id="outer" class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
    <div id="one" class="">
      header content
      <br> another line
      <br> And another
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="bg-info h-100 flex-grow">
      main content that I want to expand to cover remaining available height
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="">
      footer content
    </div>
  </div>        

    `,
    styles: [':host {flex: 1 0 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column }']
  })
```

I've updated the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KfKJt?p=preview).